# I want to generate two references pulses (Rising and Falling) generated from rising and falling edges of the reference pulse clock signal

Tags: digital-logic, cmos, pll

I want to generate two references pulses (Rising and Falling) generated from rising and falling edges of the reference pulse clock signal.  How can I do this with CMOS logic ?

Comment: XOR to clock with RC delay on one input

Comment: So 2 input XOR gate with 1 input Ref Clock, other input is just an RC circuit with time constant of clock frequency ?

Comment: Yes 50% of Vdd for transition instead of 64% for T=RC then choose PW50. R >= 300 Ohms

Comment: But wont this edge detector detect all edges including rising and falling ?  I just to separate the rising and falling edge from one another to use elsewhere - how would I do this after the edge detector

Comment: Then AND both Clock and INV CLK or NAND to separate.  There are other ways with diodes + RC for each with a buffer then must use very small C to prevent ESD overdrive.

Comment: Okay, take the output of the edge detector, put it to 2 AND gates, and then you have rising and falling edge outputs?

Comment: Yes 2f pulse AND high or AND CLK!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112096/discussion-between-sheeple-and-tony-stewart-sunnyskyguy-ee75).

Comment: Do you need it spelled out in symbolic language?

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvjygY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I used XNOR and NOR instead of XOR and AND.

### Crystal Ball comment

Warning... this not the way to make quadrature signals for bridges.  USe /4 FF with deadtime 4x clock and transition deadtime. If so, your question needs improvement.

Comment: Thank you for this.